# Error when trying to use subfig package instead of subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, tocloft, subfig

I am writing a report. I was using subfigure package along with tocloft.  Members at Tex Stack Exchange have suggested to use subfig package since its newer. When I tried to use it, I am getting following error.
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lotdepth already defined..

The work around for this was suggested in another post.. which is to use 
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}.

As I want to avoid subfigure package, what is the other option to avoid this error.

Comment: Just leave it as it is. `subfigure` option is alright.

Comment: Did you delete the .aux and .lof files after making the switch?

Comment: Looking at your code, loading `subfigure` is one of your least worries. Your preamble is a mess, outdated packages, packages loaded more than once, crazy stuff everywhere.

Comment: As I am new to latex . I am using suggestions available in net to make my preamble. Is it possible to to post the preamble and get help to structure it.

Comment: You are a member for two and a half years. You are dragging on bad habits. There is no place to dumb the preamble as people don't know what you need. For example, i wouldn't tell you to use `subfig`, but to use `subcaption` instead. A question like that would be not only opinion based, but also too broad.

Comment: Is your question answered, by the way?

Comment: No. Though subfigure option is a temporary solution.

Comment: `subfigure` is the option name to use when loading `subfig` **or** `subfigure`. This isn't a workaround. It is the documented way to make `tocloft` work with any of those two packages. It is just a misunderstanding from your side. The option name could as well have been `makesubfigurescompatibeltotocloft`.

Comment: Is there any news here?